# hiding process icon to run in background

Tags: vb.net, winforms, taskbar

I have a programs path..like utorrent and it pid too. I have achieved these values programatically using vb.net. I just want to hide their icon form tray just to run them in background and if possible attach the process with a hotkey to call them back. Is there any way to achieve this.

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Imports TrayHelper

Public Class Form1
    Dim x1, y1 As Single
    Friend WithEvents lv As New ListView With {.Parent = Me, .Dock = DockStyle.Fill}


    Private il As New ImageList
    Dim nxt As Integer
    Friend WithEvents mnuContextMenu As New ContextMenu() 'Moved this to be declared as global
    Dim mnuItemHide As New MenuItem()
    Dim mnuItemExit As New MenuItem()
    Dim things As List(Of TrayButton) = TrayHelper.Tray.GetTrayButtons()

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.Controls.Add(lv)
        lv.View = View.Details


        il.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit
        lv.SmallImageList = il
        lv.Columns.Add("Button Text", 300, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        lv.Columns.Add("PID", 50, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        lv.Columns.Add("Process Path", 600, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        'Dim things As List(Of TrayButton) = TrayHelper.Tray.GetTrayButtons()
        For Each b As TrayButton In things
            If b.Icon IsNot Nothing Then
                il.Images.Add(b.TrayIndex.ToString, b.Icon)
            Else
                ' When we can't find an icon, the listview will display this form's one.
                ' You could try to grab the icon from the process path I suppose. 
                il.Images.Add(b.TrayIndex.ToString, Me.Icon)
            End If
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(b.Text)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ProcessIdentifier.ToString)
            lvi.SubItems.Add(b.ProcessPath)
            lvi.ImageKey = b.TrayIndex.ToString
            lv.Items.Add(lvi)
        Next
        lv.MultiSelect = False
        'lv.ContextMenu = mnuContextMenu 'Don`t need to add if done this way

        lv.FullRowSelect = True 'Added this but, you don`t need it if you don`t want it


        mnuItemHide.Text = "&Hide"
        mnuItemExit.Text = "&Exit"
        mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(mnuItemHide)
        mnuContextMenu.MenuItems.Add(mnuItemExit)


        AddHandler mnuItemHide.Click, AddressOf Me.menuItem1_Click


     End Sub

    Private Sub lv_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles lv.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
            If lv.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y) IsNot Nothing Then
                lv.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y).Selected = True
                mnuContextMenu.Show(lv, New Point(e.X, e.Y))
                mnuItemExit.Visible = True
                mnuItemHide.Visible = True

            End If

        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub menuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim txtValue as String
        txtValue = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems(2).Text
        Kill(txtValue)

        Dim txtValue1 As String
        txtValue1 = lv.FocusedItem.SubItems(0).Text
        MessageBox.Show(txtValue1 + " has been hidden")

    End Sub

End Class
```

this is my code

Comment: Yes there is, but what have you tried yourself and why does it fail?
This isn't a get-a-solution-easy for you questions, try to put a little effort in it by finding out yourself and ask questions when you fail. You'll learn a lot more that way. Any way. You probaly want to start from here; http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start-vbnet

Comment: i have added what i have tried till now

Comment: Are these processes that your program starts?  Or are you trying to write a program which can hide and show system tray icons for arbitrary programs?

Comment: @adrian you got me right...i want to hide the arbitrary tray icons...

Answer (score 1):

To hide your form -> `form1.visible=false`
 
To hide your form from taskbar -> `form1.ShowinTaskbar=false`
then go to the `form1 keydown event` and put this...

```
If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.Q Then ' ---> activate with Ctrl-Q
   form1.visible=true
End If
```